# Django - How To Update Value From Views ? and How to Parse Id to get_success_url for DetailView?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, detailview

How To Update Value From Views ? And Parse Id to DetailView ?

1. Problem Update Value
   I Try to write query.attendance and query.status, to get data from database. but the error said **"'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'attendance' / 'status'"**
2. Problem Parse Id
   I dont now how to parse this id to get_success_url

**1. home/views.py**

```
class HomeView(FormView):
     template_name = 'home/index.html'
     form_class = TicketForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    getId = form.cleaned_data['nomor_ticket']
    query = Graduates.objects.filter(ticket_id=getId)
    if query:
        **#FIRST ERROR (attendance and status has no attribute)**
        print(query.attendance == timezone.now())
        print(query.status == True)
        **#FIRST END ERROR**
        print('ticket available')
    else:
        print('no ticket not found ')
    print(query)
    return super().form_valid(form)
    

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('attendance:index' + how to get id ?)
```

**2. attendance/models.py**

```
class StudyProgram(models.Model):
    study_program_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Graduates(models.Model):
   ticket_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16, unique=True, 
   default=custom_id)
   graduate_number = models.IntegerField()
   student_id = models.IntegerField()
   full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   study_program = models.ForeignKey(StudyProgram, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   attendance = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False) 
   status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**3. attendance/views.py**

```
class Attendance(DetailView):
    model = Graduates
    template_name = "attendance/index.html"
```

**4. attendance/urls.py**

```
 from django.urls import path
 from . import views

 app_name = 'attendance'
 urlpatterns = [
    path('<pk>/', views.Attendance.as_view(), name='index'),
 ]
```

**5. home/form.py**

```
from django import forms
from attendance.models import Graduates

class TicketForm(forms.Form):
    nomor_ticket = forms.CharField(label="No Tiket ", required=True)
```

**6. home/templates/home/index.html**

```
#apart of index.html
....
<!-- Modal body -->
<div class="p-6 space-y-6">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
</div>
<!-- Modal footer -->
<div
  class="flex items-center p-6 space-x-2 rounded-b border-t border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600"
>
  <button
    data-modal-toggle="defaultModal"
    type="submit"
    class="text-white bg-[#7f1d1d] hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-bold rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
  >
    Cek Tiketmu
  </button>
</form>
....
```

Comment: Share your `TicketForm` and `index.html` template.

Comment: @SunderamDubey already edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Your `query` object is of type `QuerySet`, not `Graduate`. You have to do something like:

```
try:
    graduate = Graduate.objects.get(ticket_id=getId)
except Graduate.DoesNotExist:
    print('no ticket not found ')
```

2 Just forget `get_success_url`. Do the redirect in `form_valid` method. The last line in `form_valid`:

```
return super().form_valid(form)
```

is nothing more of doing a redirect.

So your `home/views.py` would look like:

```
class HomeView(FormView):
    template_name = 'home/index.html'
    form_class = TicketForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        getId = form.cleaned_data['nomor_ticket']
        try:
            graduate = Graduate.objects.get(ticket_id=getId)
            print(graduate.attendance == timezone.now())
            print(graduate.status == True)
            print('ticket available')
        except Graduate.DoesNotExist:
            print('no ticket not found ')
        print(graduate)
        return redirect('attendance:index', graduate.ticket_id)
```